# The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference

Tags: java, maven

The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='org.spigotmc:spigot:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph org.spigotmc:spigot:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT --> org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT --> org.spigotmc:spigot:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT

Edge between 'Vertex{label='org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='org.spigotmc:spigot:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph org.spigotmc:spigot:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT --> org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT --> org.spigotmc:spigot:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spigot</name>
    <url>http://www.spigotmc.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <api.version>unknown</api.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <minecraft.version>1.8.8</minecraft.version>
        <minecraft_version>1_8_R3</minecraft_version>
        <buildtag.prefix>git-Bukkit-</buildtag.prefix>
        <buildtag.suffix></buildtag.suffix>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-parent</artifactId>
        <version>dev-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.trove4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>trove4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>minecraft-server</artifactId>
            <version>${minecraft.version}-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jline</groupId>
            <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.14</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- required until fixed plexus-compiler-eclipse is deployed -->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spigotmc-public</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <!-- This builds a completely 'ready to start' jar with all dependencies inside -->
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
                <artifactId>scriptus</artifactId>
                <version>0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ex-spigot</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <format>git-Spigot-%s</format>
                            <scmDirectory>../</scmDirectory>
                            <descriptionProperty>spigot.desc</descriptionProperty>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>describe</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ex-craftbukkit</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <format>-%s</format>
                            <scmDirectory>../../CraftBukkit</scmDirectory>
                            <descriptionProperty>craftbukkit.desc</descriptionProperty>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>describe</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>  
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main</Main-Class>
                            <Implementation-Title>CraftBukkit</Implementation-Title>
                            <Implementation-Version>${spigot.desc}${craftbukkit.desc}</Implementation-Version>
                            <Implementation-Vendor>Bukkit Team</Implementation-Vendor>
                            <Specification-Title>Bukkit</Specification-Title>
                            <Specification-Version>${api.version}</Specification-Version>
                            <Specification-Vendor>Bukkit Team</Specification-Vendor>
                        </manifestEntries>
                        <manifestSections>
                            <manifestSection>
                                <name>net/bukkit/</name>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Sealed>true</Sealed>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </manifestSection>
                            <manifestSection>
                                <name>com/bukkit/</name>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Sealed>true</Sealed>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </manifestSection>
                            <manifestSection>
                                <name>org/bukkit/</name>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Sealed>true</Sealed>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </manifestSection>
                        </manifestSections>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <signature>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                        <artifactId>java16</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </signature>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>joptsimple</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.joptsimple</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>jline</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.ibex</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.org.ibex</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.gjt</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.org.gjt</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.bukkit.craftbukkit</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v${minecraft_version}</shadedPattern>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>net.minecraft.server</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>net.minecraft.server.v${minecraft_version}</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Gotta go after shade plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
                <artifactId>specialsource-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>remap</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <srgIn>${project.basedir}/deprecation-mappings.csrg</srgIn>
                            <accessIn>${project.basedir}/deprecation-mappings.at</accessIn>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- versions after this appear to be broken -->
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- we use the Eclipse compiler as it doesn't need a JDK -->
                    <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                    <!-- source and target are ignored if this isn't true -->
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- we need our custom version as it fixes some bugs on case sensitive file systems -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.0-spigotmc</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-server</workingDirectory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org/bukkit/craftbukkit/inventory/ItemStack*Test.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

other pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spigot-API</name>
    <url>http://www.spigotmc.org/</url>
    <description>An enhanced plugin API for Minecraft servers.</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- just until we get deployment to central approved -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-releases</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>spigotmc-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <!-- required until fixed plexus-compiler-eclipse is deployed -->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spigotmc-public</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- bundled with Minecraft, should be kept in sync -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>17.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- bundled with Minecraft, should be kept in sync -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.avaje</groupId>
            <artifactId>ebean</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
            <artifactId>bungeecord-chat</artifactId>
            <version>1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- versions after this appear to be broken -->
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- we use the Eclipse compiler as it doesn't need a JDK -->
                    <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                    <!-- source and target are ignored if this isn't true -->
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- we need our custom version as it fixes some bugs on case sensitive file systems -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.0-spigotmc</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <signature>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                        <artifactId>java16</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </signature>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- utterly useless artifact from shade 2.x -->
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <!-- when downloading via Maven we can pull depends individually -->
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly what is described - spigot-api has a dependency on spigot and spigot has a dependency on spigot-api.  Each one needs the other to exist to build, so there is no way to build this all from scratch.

You will need to fix these projects so you can build one without the other first - probably the API project should not rely on its implementation so try removing the dependency on spigot from the spigot-api project.